# Azure Logic Apps - Is there a separate library/api to instantiate functions in expressions?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

May I know if **there is a separate library/api of azure logic app that we could use to instantiate [functions in expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference)**?

We're using logic app for scheduling in our products, and would love to keep the same expression resolving behavior beyond scheduling scenario.
Below is an example to demonstrate two scenarios, and my question is not limited to the function itself.

- scheduling scenario: in below workflow, we use function @addToTime(@utcNow(), 1, 'Day') for scheduling HTTP request.
- single request without logic app: we have to implement the function resolving logic from scratch. This also makes the two scenarios different.

```
{
  'location': '{LogicAppRegion}',
  'properties': {
    'state': '{LogicAppState}',
    'definition': {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#',
      'actions': {
        'HTTP': {
          'inputs': {
            'body': {"ParameterAssignments": {"time": "@addToTime(@utcNow(), 1, 'Day')"}},
            'method': 'POST',
            'uri': '{LogicAppUri}'
          },
          'runAfter': { },
          'type': 'Http'
        }
      },
      'contentVersion': '1.0.0.0',
      'outputs': { },
      'triggers': {
        'Recurrence': {
          'recurrence': {recurrence},
          'type': 'Recurrence'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the workarounds that you can try.
I have added `Recurrence` connector and then used a `HTTP` action connector instead of `HTTP request` trigger this helped to satisfy both the requirements

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "uri": "<Your Required URI>"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Http"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Here is the screenshot for your reference
[image]

Comment: Thanks @SwethaKandikonda-MT for answering. However, I'm looking for a way to resolve logic app built-in functions outside, and the function I used in the case is just an example. I think logic app may implement by call a library in filling actual value of functions, do you know where or how user could use such a lib?